# ASP.NET UpdatePanel not working, it refreshes the whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, autopostback

I'm new in using `UpdatePanel`, I Have 2 DropDownList:
`DropDownList_1` and `DropDownList_2`
where `DropDownList_2` content will be dependent to `DropDownList_1` selected value, here is my code:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="businessgroup" DataTextField="BusinessGroupName" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList_1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_2" runat="server" DataSourceID="jobposition" DataTextField="JobPositionName" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**CS:**

```
protected void DropDownList_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [JobPosition] WHERE BusinessGroupID ="+DropDownList_1.SelectedValue;
    DropDownList_2.DataBind();
}
```

its working as stated above but what I doesn't want in my output is the whole page refreshes, I also tried removing `AutoPostBack="true"` in my DropDownList_1 but it stops working, what am I doing wrong in here? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I also tried moving the DropDownList_2 inside UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate but still the whole page is refreshing.

Comment: Your DropDownList_2 is outside UpdatePanel when you do DataBind() for it the page gets refreshed.

Comment: Hi demonplus, thanks for your comment, but I just tried moving the DropDownList_2 inside UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate and it's not working.

Comment: Make sure AutoPostBack="true" for the first DropDownList, it is necessary.

Comment: as stated above, DropDownList_1 has AutoPostBack="true" but still the whole page refreshes.

Comment: Worth mentioning here, even though this doesn't apply to your case at hand: An `UpdatePanel` won't work as desired if one if it's elements has `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix, thanks to Cristina for reminding me to check the console errors. And just for reference to anyone who is having the same problem here is what I've done:

1. I have missing Ajax libraries, so I imported the MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftAjaxWebService in this folder Scripts>WebForms>MSAjax.
2. After I imported the necessary Ajax library I've got this console error:

> MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6 Uncaught
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

What I did is add `EnableEventValidation="false"` inside this Ajax page, in <%Page %> directive.

And after that I have no longer full page reload and all is working now on how I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should do:

- If you want to refresh the second drop-down, than the second drop-down should be inside an update panel
- Set `AutoPostBack="true"` only for the second drop-down
- Set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for the update panel (otherwise they will refresh every time)
- Set the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` of the panel to point to the first drop-down `SelectedIndexChanged` event
- Set `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` for the Update panel

:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>     
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="businessgroup" DataTextField="BusinessGroupName" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="jobposition" DataTextField="JobPositionName" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList_1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The controls should reside in the same update panel, it's simpler this way.

Comment: Hi Cristina, thanks I appreciate your answer, but the functionality of my two DropDownList is fully functional, my only problem here is the refreshing of the whole page instead of DropDownList_2 only, I also tried some of your suggestions like moving the second dropdown inside the update panel, adding the UpdateMode="Conditional" and ChildrenAsTriggers="true", moving the autopostback in the second dropdown but the output is still the same, the whole page still refreshes.

Comment: The problem appears when you select an item from the first drop-down? Is this the trigger for the postback?

Comment: Yes that's right, when I select an item in DropDownList_1, the whole page refreshes because of the AutoPostBack, that's why I used an UpdatePanel because I doesn't want the whole page to refresh but instead the DropDownList_2 only

Comment: Other suggestions from my side would be: 1.check for javascript errors, 2.check that your update panel is not inside a table row

Comment: Also, try to set `EnablePartialRendering="true"` on the script manager.

Comment: I almost forgot to check for console errors, thanks for reminding me, I've got several ajax errors, first is ajax library is missing since i'm making my website from scratch, second is i'm getting Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException, I just add EnableEventValidation="false" in my page and now it works well as I want it, Thanks for your help Cristina, appreciated it :)

Answer (score 1):

If your panel still posts back after you've set it up as per guidelines, check that you have not set `ClientIDMode="Static"` either for the specific control performing the callback or by causing the ClientIDMode to default to static inherited from either  in web.config, the Page or parent containers.

Search your solution for `ClientIDMode="Static"` and either change this for inherited controls including the one triggering the postback, or explicitly set `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` or `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` for each of your controls that trigger a postback.

Answer (score 0):

While you are working with update panel you have to register your events while refreshing the page for that you have to use Microsoft's PageRequestManager
to re-subscribe every update.

You have to initialize your event in the `document.ready(function(){})` 
of the `javascript`.

Ex: `var test=Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();`